# Helidon HttpServletRequest headers

Tags: servlets, microprofile, helidon

I need to get HTTP Headers in my Helidon MP project.
How can I get `HttpServletRequest` object to extract the headers from there?

I have tried to look at the API but I have not found Servlet at all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Helidon is not a Servlet Container, so there is no Servlet in it, and thus you can't access `HttpServletRequest`.

Helidon MP is a MicroProfile implementation, which means by definition that it is also a Jakarta RESTful Web Services implementation (formerly JAX-RS)—it packages Jersey. By the time you're talking about requests and responses, you are "in" Jersey, and so you do things the Jersey way;

So then: most, if not all, of the things you can do with an `HttpServletRequest` you can do with equivalent Jakarta RESTful Web Services constructs. For example, you can `@Inject` an instance of `HttpHeaders` to get the HTTP headers you need.

Please check https://github.com/helidon-io/helidon/wiki/FAQ for more details.

Comment: Thank you! I will check Jax-Rs!